# Why SparkUI doesn't show memory usage for SparkSQL LRU cache?

Tags: caching, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, lru

When I run sql query spark-sql will use LRU cache. 
Why LRU cache usage doesn't reflects in spark's WebUI? According responce time I feel my queries cached, but "Memory Used" says "0.0 B / 707.0 MB"
Spark version is 1.3.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Spark does show the caching status.
It's available via Spark application UI on the ["Storage"](https://www.datastax.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/SparkStorageDetail.png) tab.
It will show the storage-level (cache type), number of cached partitions, size in memory & size on disk.

You didn't specify how you use Spark caching mechanism.
Spark caching has to be enabled explicitly.
You can check [here](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-programming-guide.html#caching-data-in-memory) how to enable/disable caching for Spark tables

You can also enable the cache for RDDs/DataFrams using:

```
rdd.cache() / df.cache() 
rdd.persist(StorageLevel newLevel) / df.persist(StorageLevel newLevel)
```